# Book about young S.W.A.T. agent that falls in love with a woman that has a child (Wattpad)

Tags: identification-request, short-stories

I am looking for a book/short story on Wattpad about a young man (22-27) who is a sniper for a S.W.A.T. team. In the beginning of the book he is forced to take a kill shot due to something silly that one of his team members did.

He later falls in love with a woman who has a small son (3-5). At the end of the story the man saves the kid from a building (which was on fire if I recall correctly). He jumps out of a 2nd story window with the kid on his back. But because he and the woman argued before that occurred, he thinks that her admission of love was due to the fact that he saved her son and "owes him".

Comment: I’ve never used wattpad, but does it not have a way to access your reading history?

Comment: @Spagirl It does, but my old account got hacked (way back in the day when Wattpad was starting out). So I am trying to look for the story on my new account.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It’s called "Enjoying the Chase" by Kirsty Moseley.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi and welcome to Literature Stack Exchange. I wonder if you could add a few more details, e.g. if the details described in the question match with what you found in the novel. (Memory is fallible, so some details might not match.)

Answer (score 0):

Writing this as a separate answer, since it involves some additional details, but it looks like this was published as a book as *[Nothing Left to Lose](https://a.co/d/0XaY18H)* by Kirsty Mosely with the title *[Enjoying the Chase](https://a.co/d/8ppQlVY)* being used for a companion novel, sometimes considered to be the third book of the *Guarded Hearts* trilogy whose first book is *Nothing Left to Lose* (the second book being *[Blurring the Lines](https://a.co/d/2EBV9Re)*, which is a more direct sequel).

> This book contains both parts of Nothing Left to Lose: Guarding the Broken, and Blurring the Lines and combines them into one book of epic proportions! Annabelle Spencer’s life is every girl’s dream. She has wonderful parents, great friends, and of course the perfect boyfriend, Jack Roberts. That all changes on her sixteenth birthday when her life comes crashing down around her. Her dream night turns into a nightmare when Jack is murdered right in front of her, and she’s kidnapped by his murderer, Carter Thomas, a big time drug and arms dealer. After ten months of being with Carter, she’s found, but the experience has totally changed her. She’s no longer the happy-go-lucky girl that everyone used to know and love; she’s now cold, hard and suffers from night terrors. It appears that Carter broke not only her body, but her spirit too. A shadow of her former self, her slogan for life is now: ‘If you don’t care about anything, then you have nothing to lose’. Carter is currently serving time for the murder of Jack, a conviction that Anna helped secure. But his retrial is coming up because some key evidence appears to have been tampered with. Unbeknown to Anna, death threats are being received by her father, the Senator. It appears that Carter is still interested in Anna and will stop at nothing to get her back. Ashton Taylor is brought in to protect her. He’s a newly qualified SWAT agent, a bright spark, the agency’s new golden boy. He is assigned undercover, posing as her boyfriend. His job is to help her through college and keep her safe until the end of the trial in eight months’ time. For three years she has been the broken, damaged girl, refusing to feel emotion or pain, but can Ashton help her rebuild her life and finally deal with the grief of losing her childhood sweetheart? Will he be the one to make her see that life is, in fact, worth living and that not all men will hurt her? All the while, the shadow of the trial looms over the both of them, taunting them, reminding them that it isn’t over yet. After all, Carter Thomas will stop at nothing to be reunited with his ‘Princess’.